# Display of comment_date within get_comments?

Tags: comments

Any way to change how the date is displayed with get_comments..?

I have the following..

```
 <?php
       $comments = get_comments( array(
       'post_id' => $post->ID,
       'number' => 4,
       'status' => 'approve'
       ) );

       foreach($comments as $comment) :
       echo "<li class=clearfix>
       <span class=comment-details>{$comment->comment_content}</span>
       <span class=comment-date>{$comment->comment_date}</span>
       <span class=comment-author>By {$comment->comment_author}</span>

       </li>";
       endforeach;

?>
```

Comes out with something like.. 2012-02-20 17:09:07 when i just want something like 6th January 2011

Comment: Have you checked what settings you've made for time display and such in the back-end/admin UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're doing this, you're going to get the raw SQL date that's stored in the wp_comments table.

You can still use the convenience functions like `comment_date` with `get_comments`.  In this case, we'll use `get_comment_date`.  The first argument is the date format -- if you leave it blank, WP will use whatever date format is set in the options > general page.

```
<?php
foreach($comments as $comment) :
   echo "<li class=clearfix>
   <span class=comment-details>{$comment->comment_content}</span>";
   echo '<span class=comment-date>' . get_comment_date( '', $comment ) . '</span>';
   echo "<span class=comment-author>By {$comment->comment_author}</span>

   </li>";
endforeach;
```

Otherwise you could use PHP's `strtotime` and `date` to generate the date format you want.

```
date('F j, Y', strtotime($comment->comment_date));
```